# Error Too Many Redirects NGINX with Next.js / Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: nginx, next.js

I have a Docker container with a Next.js application running at `indiestash:3007`. I want to be able to load it up using a reverse proxy (NGINX) when I visit '/' location.

Here is my NGINX config:

```
worker_processes 1;
 
events { worker_connections 1024; }
 
http {
  server {
        listen 80;

        server_name website.dev;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://indiestash:3007;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
}
```

When I access the `/` location, I can load the content of the Nextjs app but some of the static js gets blocked due to `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

[image]

Doing some research it looks like all files with the error are coming from "/_next/static". I would assume everything should match the / location block and be directed into the indiestash:3007 app. Is this not the case?

Also the app loads fine if it directly accessed (without NGINX). How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you find the solution for it? I need it, I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

False alarm. Looks like it's a caching issue. Loading in an incognito session, I can see the expected result.

Comment: Then you'd better delete your question?

Comment: Leaving it so someone in future can take a look

Comment: I emptied cache  and hard reloaded and it worked.

Comment: btw it was helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing similar errors on my next application with Nginx but Sometimes it appeared and sometimes it resolved automatically. I am not sure what is happening with the app.